# Break out of SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way you can execute only part of a SQL procedure?
I'm trying to put some code in my procedure that will tell me what version that procedure is when I feed it a command word as an argument. I am doing this because I need to update this procedure on multiple DBs at different times and want to verify if a certain DB has the latest version or not. Just house keeping.
The problem is that while I know I can use an IF to return a message "SQL Proc ver 4.0" I do not know how to tell the procedure to end there instead of going trough the rest of it's code.

Comment: A RETURN command will force your procedure to end at that point. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RETURN](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the keyword you are looking for. You can supply an integer as result, like `RETURN 0`, but it's optional.

The procedure won't continue it's execution after that, nor jump to a `CATCH` if any.

Comment: Thank you, @EzLo. Your solution was just what I needed.